# How to prevent : 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY

Tags: vb.net

**1. SHOWS ERROR AT READER= CMD.EXECUTEREADER
: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Stock'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Stock'. The duplicate key value is ( ,  ,  ,  ,  ).
The statement has been terminated.'**

*2. HOW TO ALLOW RECORDS TO ADD
3. THIS IS CODE BELOW*

```
     `   Private Sub InsertStockDatagrid()
            Dim cmdstk As String
            Try
                con.Open()
    
                cmd.Connection = con
    
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            For Each Rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                cmdstk = " Insert into Stock (Code, Qty, Rate, Amt, Taxable, cgstamt, sgstamt)
                values('" & Rw.Cells(15).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(6).Value.ToString() & "',
                '" & Rw.Cells(7).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(13).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(13).Value.ToString() & "',
                '" & Rw.Cells(11).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(12).Value.ToString() & "')"
    
                Dim Stkquery = String.Concat(cmdstk, ";")
                cmd = New SqlCommand(Stkquery, con)
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    reader.Close()
                    End
    
                    con.Close()
                Next
    
            MessageBox.Show("Stock Data Entered")
            
        End Sub `
```

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear. You try to insert a duplicate primary key to table stock. So you have to check which column(s) define the primary key and before the Insert you have to check if table Stock already contains it.

Comment: The DataGridView counts the empty row waiting for input as a row. Perhaps that is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Database objects like Command and Connection need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` take care of this even if there is an error. Don't declare these objects outside the method where they are used.

You can pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the Command.

Do not write `Try` blocks with empty `Catch` blocks. They just swallow errors.

**Never** concatenate strings to build sql statements. **Always** use parameters.

Don't create a new command on each iteration of your loop. The only thing that changes is the value of the parameters.

You don't want to `ExecuteReader`. That is for retrieving data. Update, Insert and Delete are considered non queries.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub InsertStockDatagrid()
    Dim cmdstk As String = " Insert into Stock (Code, Qty, Rate, Amt, Taxable, cgstamt, sgstamt)
            values(@Code, @Qty, @Rate, @Amt, @Taxable, @CG, @SG);"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdstk, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@Oty", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@Amt", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@Taxable", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@CG", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            .Add("@SG", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        End With
        con.Open()
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            cmd.Parameters("@Code").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("@Qty").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("@Rate").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("@Amt").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("@Taxable").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("@CG").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters("SG").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value.ToString()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        InsertStockDatagrid()
        MessageBox.Show("Stock Data Entered")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I question your database design. Your code indicated that every field is a string type. Qty would almost always be an Integer. Money is handled by a Decimal type. Please check the database for types of all the fields. Adjust the code accordingly. If they really are all strings and it is not too late, please correct the datatypes. I would also suggest that your primary key field be set up as an identity field. No value would be sent with an insert.